# Python 2.7.8 list index out of range in console, but codeskulptor is ok with the code

Tags: python, list, traceback

Running python script from a DOS window.

I have to resolve the problem in my console script:
G:\python\lri_parse>python b1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b1.py", line 115, in 
    elif data_line[-1] == 'n':
IndexError: list index out of range

Example in codeskulptor works great:

```
a = ['BORDER', '2199.497', '3793.552', 'n', '2420.493', '3793.552', 'n']

last = a[-1]
print last
#if last == 'n':
if a[-1] == 'n':
    print 'Last list item is:', a[-1]
    print 'Last list item is:', last
```

Codeskulptor returns:

```
    n
    Last list item is: n
    Last list item is: n
```

This is desired behavior; I want to check if the last item in the list == 'n'.
Tried both my non-working direct method, and a variable assignment (which I feel should not be necessary).

Since the console code is different, I'm including the relevant piece here.
data_line is a variable that contains similar data to the codeskulptor example.

```
    elif data_line[-1] == 'n':
        print data_line[-1]
        print len(data_line)
        print type(data_line)
    elif (data_len == 1) and (end_roads in data_line):
        pass
    else:
```

Putting a variable assign into the console script also fails with the same traceback:

```
    last = data_line[-1]
    if last == 'n':
```

Thanks

Update: the following code does what I need, but the question remains why the console does not like my original construct, and how can I resolve that without a variable assign?

```
    elif 'n' in data_line:
    if data_line[(len(data_line) - 1)] == 'n':
        print 'Last element is n.'
```

Comment: are you positive `data_line` has data in it? can you print `data_line`

Comment: It probably means that `data_line` is empty.

Comment: Hm.  I will check that.

Comment: you could use `data_line[-1:] == ['n']`  to avoid the `IndexError`

Comment: excellent, thank you.  And source does contain blank lines, which are not caught earlier - sigh.  Always check your assumptions!  Thanks!

Comment: Chris_Rands - this worked: comments apparently are only one line, so this is going to mangle my code indents.  Check for empty lines and skip them, so this works:         if data_line[-1] == 'n':